# Run-time error '1004' - OFFICE UPDATE

Tags: vba, excel, runtime

I updated my office 365 and I am trying to run the simple code below but Im getting an error:

---

Rows("5:5").Select

Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

---

Error message:

Run-time error '1004'

This selection isn't valid. Make sure the copy and paste areas don't overlap unless they are the same size and shape

Surprisingly, if I record the same code and run the code is fine.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Try simplifying the code to `Rows("5:5").Insert Shift:=xlDown` on one line instead of your two. You don't need to "select" a range and then apply the operation to the selection, you can just apply an operation to a range directly!

Comment: I mean, I would like to know if anyone else is having the same problem or if microsoft has released some correction.  It is absolutely impossible the code just stop working overnight :(  We have like more than 50 vba tools  that use the same code..

Comment: WIth 365 there were lots of updates that affect VBA. Where I work, there was an MS service for getting code inspected and rewrote to be compatible with 365. Most people used it. I guess you guys didn't...

Comment: Rows(5).Insert  is gerneral method.

Comment: I found the problem : Excel: Feature updates
This channel release contains the following feature updates:
• Retain copy: Copy your cells, and before you paste, you can still do other tasks like typing or inserting cells.